# python tkinter center button

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I wrote this calculator in python:

```py
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('200x290')
window.title('Rechner')

gui_items = list()
button_values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
                 '+', '-', '*', '/', '=', 'AC']

calculation = str()

def add_button_text_to_calculation(value):
    global calculation

    if value == 'AC':
        calculation = str()
        output_label['text'] = '...'
        return

    if value == '=':
        calculate(calculation)
        calculation = str()
        return

    calculation = calculation + value
    output_label['text'] = calculation

def create_button(value):
    button = tkinter.Button(text=value,command=lambda: add_button_text_to_calculation(value))
    gui_items.append(button)

for val in button_values:
    create_button(val)

output_label = tkinter.Label(text='Type something')
output_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=10)

column_count = 0
row_count = 1
maximum_columns = 3

for item in gui_items:
    item.grid(row=row_count, column=column_count)
```

How can I center the block of buttons? that the buttons don't overlap and the block of buttons is centerd not that I have to make a position for each of them

Comment: Try using the `grid()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You use the grid layout manager. This work by slicing your parent object (for example a Window) to rows and columns according to the biggest row/column value you set. You should give unique row and column values to each object you place. The easiest way of doing so is changing the last two lines:

```
for item in range(len(gui_items)):
    gui_items[item].grid(row=1+item//4, column=1+item%4)
```

I added +1 to the rows because you don't want the new Buttons to hide your Label which is at the 0th row. You can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
How can I center the block of buttons? that the buttons don't overlap and the block of buttons is centered not that I have to make a position for each of them
```

Comment out in below. So you already `append` in `gui_items`.

```
column_count = 0
row_count = 1
maximum_columns = 3

for item in gui_items:
    item.grid(row=row_count, column=column_count)
```

Missing `Button` widget location in `create_button` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('200x440')  
window.title('Rechner')

gui_items = list()
button_values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
                 '+', '-', '*', '/', '=', 'AC']

calculation = str()

def add_button_text_to_calculation(value):
    global calculation

    if value == 'AC':
        calculation = str()
        output_label['text'] = '...'
        return

    if value == '=':
        #calculate(calculation)
        calculation = str()
        return

    calculation = calculation + value
    output_label['text'] = calculation

def create_button(value):
    button = tkinter.Button(window, text=value,
                            command=lambda: add_button_text_to_calculation(value))
    button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
    
    gui_items.append(button)
     
     
for val in button_values:
    create_button(val)

output_label = tkinter.Label(window,text='Type something', width=50)
output_label.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)


window.mainloop
```

Screenshot:

[image]